# jQuery change class on click of Checkbox Working After Several Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have set the following jQuery code:

```js
$('#check').change(function(){
if (this.checked){
$('#check').click(function() {
$("#rk").addClass('disabled', this.checked);
$("#rkBtn").removeClass('disabled', this.checked);
});
} else {
$("#rk").removeClass('disabled', this.checked);
$("#rkBtn").addClass('disabled', this.checked);
}   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field text-left">
<label class="text-left">Rk</label>
<input type="text" id="rk" class="rk" name="rk" placeholder="00.00.00 - 000.00" onkeyup="showHint(this.value,'rk')" />

</div>
<div class="field">
<input id="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
<label class="title-checkbox">Tick this Checkbox.</label>
</div>
<div class="field">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="">
<a href="#" id="rkBtn" class="btn disabled"Next Step</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to remove or add a class on click of the checkbox. At the same time when checkbox is clicked, I'm disabling the input field above it. Strangely enough it works, but only after I click on the checkbox on the fourth time.

Can you help please?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because you don't need use `click` with `change` function at the same time. that's all.

```js
$('#check').change(function(){
if (this.checked){
//$('#check').click(function() {
$("#rk").addClass('disabled', this.checked);
$("#rkBtn").removeClass('disabled', this.checked);
//});
} else {
$("#rk").removeClass('disabled', this.checked);
$("#rkBtn").addClass('disabled', this.checked);
}   
});
```

```css
.disabled {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field text-left">
<label class="text-left">Rk</label>
<input type="text" id="rk" class="rk" name="rk" placeholder="00.00.00 - 000.00" onkeyup="showHint(this.value,'rk')" />

</div>
<div class="field">
<input id="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
<label class="title-checkbox">Tick this Checkbox.</label>
</div>
<div class="field">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="">
<a href="#" id="rkBtn" class="btn disabled"Next Step</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome! @maltesers down vote is so funny here!

Answer (score 0):

First, just get rid of that click event binding:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#check").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#rk").addClass("disabled", this.checked);
      $("#rkBtn").removeClass("disabled", this.checked);
    } else {
      $("#rk").removeClass("disabled", this.checked);
      $("#rkBtn").addClass("disabled", this.checked);
    }
  });
});
```

Second, your anchor tag has syntax error

```
<a href="#" id="rkBtn" class="btn disabled"Next Step</a>
```

Should be

```
<a href="#" id="rkBtn" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
```